# How to create applications for Windows CE

Tags: windows-ce

I'm new to the CE environment and I was wanting to create applications for a computer(Intel) running on CE(5 and up). What exactly do I need to to get started and where do I go? I have never used CE before but I do have experience writing code in C, C++, C#, and Java.

Thanks,

Comment: I have read in different articles that I need to be in an NT environment. Is this true or do can I create programs from XP Pro?

Comment: XP is just NT with a pretty face, a few more features, and a few bugs fixed along the way. All of NT, 2K, XP, Vista, and Win7 are built on the foundation of the NT kernel. CE came out around the same time as NT, so a lot of the early articles will refer to it that way.

Answer (score 5):

If you are interested in writing application using C#, do a little search for Compact Framework (CF). It is the stripped down version available in Windows CE.

Keep in mind that Windows CE is a highly customizable OS and you have no guarantee that it will have the component to support your application (that includes C#) - Windows Mobile (+PocketPC, +SmartPhone2003) is a different story.

When you develop for Windows CE you need to use Visual Studio 2005/8 Professional to have the Smart Device support. When you develop C# applications using VS2008 you target CF3.5 and when you use 2005 you target CF 2.0

Comment: VS2010 and 2013 dont support CE?

Comment: As @Antonio Bakula's answers suggests - check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_CE#Visual_Studio and you can see that VS2010 only supports Windows Phone 7. VS2012 supports CE development

Comment: any idea where i can even get my hands on a copy of Visual Studio 2008 Pro? I was having a hard enough time finding out which version/program I needed

Comment: Found this on Google: http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/1/d/81d3f35e-fa03-485b-953b-ff952e402520/VS2008ProEdition90dayTrialENUX1435622.iso

Comment: Thanks @Shaihi for this link. I've spent 2 hours searching it!

Comment: Any updates on this, what about `Visual Studio 2017`?

Comment: I suggest you ask a new updated question. In any case you can read up on the latest embedded products from MS at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee504814(v=winembedded.70).aspx
Seems Windows Embedded 2013 is the latest to have been released and you need to understand what Studio comes with the BSP...

Answer (score 3):

Look in wikipedia, link is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_CE look under Development Tools, I recommend Visual Studio 2008 and C#, here is the link to the SDK: 
[Windows Mobile 6.5 Developer Tool Kit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17284)

As of Visual Studio 2010 Windows CE development is not supported any more, here are the details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa69he4t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: What version of Visual Studio?

Comment: since you can't use 2010 (it's not supported), use Visual Studio 2008, look here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa69he4t.aspx

Answer (score 2):

To develop application for the Windows CE

- Use VS 2005 or VS 2008 which has got support for smart device application development.
- Install the Windows Mobile 6 SDK as a prerequisites.([here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6135))
- Install the Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5.3 DTK([here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5389))
- To Create Your First App. ([here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43357/Windows-Mobile-App-Development-Part-1-Creating-you))