# windows ce + application development

Tags: c#, vb.net, sql-server-ce, compact-framework, windows-ce

I know my question is a kind of repetitive to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463420/how-to-create-applications-for-windows-ce) 
However I didn't got good understanding from it. Plus after these many years i may have to take multiple new points into consideration.

Scenario:Our client has around 20 Motorola MC35 devices. They have Windows CE operating system on it. We have to develop an application for it.

I have been googling a lot but not getting answers to;

1. Can we develop database driven applications for windows CE operating system?
2. If Yes, What framework to use for it's development. Can we use .Net Compact Framework?
3. We have Visual Studio 2013. Which project template needs to be installed in VS to do required development?
4. Which emulator to use?
5. Links / samples for development

Comment: Erik's #3 is the critical part here.  Nothing newer than Studio 2008 is going to have support for your target device.  Short of an MSDN subscription, I have no idea where you'd find it.

Comment: Do you really want to develop for a device that is declared to be discontinued for 2009? What, if a device gets a hardwre defect? This device is running Windows Mobile 5 Prof. Edition without a persistent storage as in Windows Mobile 6.x. When the device is hard reset, all apps and data has to be re-installed from scratch. You possibly should think about a web based application, then you can easily switch to actual devices and do not have to start with VS2008 development (although this is OK, if youalready own a copy).

Comment: Sorry: The MC35 can also run WM6. So a hard reset is not that critical: https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/mobile-computers/handheld/mc35.html#pageandfilelist_b40a

Comment: @Josef: Thank you for your checks. I have been checking the device, it supports Wifi and GPRS. However due to device going to be used at construction sites possibility of having wifi has gone. Thus, wanted to get comment on whether the device be able to make server requests for passing information of say 10 textboxes and show grid page size 10 and columns 5.... Kindly suggest

Comment: Dev Questions: for simple data, SQL Server CF is to large, try with sqlite or simple text db. If the device needs to sync when on-site, EDGE GPRS may be used, needs a server in internet. Simplest solution will be a simple web server with a DB in back. You may concider using MCL, MobileDev or another RapidDev Tool instead of doing all the offline/online Data sync stuff yourself in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: yes, you can

2: .NET Compact Framework 3.5 and SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2

3: You need VS 2008 with Smart Device Development option chosen during install

4: If you install VS 2008, it comes with a CE emulator